# Problem to read from PIPE in posix Linux when the content size is bigger than 65536

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, pipe, posix

Why I can't strings contents from file descriptor bigger than 65536 with my code?

```
void SetFdAsync(int fd) {
  int flags;
  if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0))) flags = 0;
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
}

std::tuple<std::string, std::string> ReadPipe(int pipe_out, int pipe_err) {
  char buf[PIPE_BUF];
  char buf_err[PIPE_BUF];

  int rd = 0;
  int rd_err = 0;

  SetFdAsync(pipe_out);
  SetFdAsync(pipe_err);

  std::string str_out;
  std::string str_err;

  int i = 0;
  while ((rd = read(pipe_out, buf, PIPE_BUF)) > 0) {
    std::cout << "loop: " << i++ << std::endl;
    str_out.append(buf, rd);
  }

  while ((rd_err = read(pipe_err, buf_err, PIPE_BUF)) > 0) {
    str_err.append(buf_err, rd_err);
  }

  return std::tuple<std::string, std::string>(str_out, str_err);
}
```

Why I can't read contents when the length is bigger than 65536? What must I change?

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  In the context of a complete program, what behavior leads you to conclude that you can't read strings larger than 65536?  In a correct implementation, you certainly can, though you may have to call `read()` several times to get all of it.

Comment: By the way, I removed the [tag:c] tag since your program is obviously C++ and not C. Normally one should not tag a C++ question as C, or vice versa, even if it involves issues that might also apply indirectly to the other language. See the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info about the relationship between the tags.

Comment: @NateEldredge the loop is doing exactly this, reading several times. When the pipe came from command cat file.txt and this file.txt is bigger than 65536 I can't read this completely.

Comment: Please *show, don't tell*.  A description of what the rest of the code does is not as useful as actually seeing it.  From my experience, when someone describes what unseen code does, they are actually describing what they *intended* it to do. Very often it turns out that it actually doesn't do quite what they said, or that they left out important details, and this discrepancy is the cause of the bug; while in the meantime, much time and effort has been wasted by answers making erroneous guesses.

Comment: As a wild guess, there might be an issue if the writer is mixing writes to the `out` and `err` pipes.  If it writes a total of `PIPE_BUF` to the `err` pipe, then further writes will block, since the OS buffer is full.  But the reader is still reading from the `out` pipe instead, so the `err` pipe's buffer is never cleared out.  In effect, your writer and reader would deadlock.

Comment: So make sure your MRE includes the code that does the writing.

Comment: I plugged your function into a program and it reads large inputs just fine. You have not specified what error you are getting, but one guess is that your standard C++ library's implementation of strings is limited to 64kb per string.